# WCF Data Service Operation cast issue

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I am having a casting issue on returning what I thought was an IQueryable from a service operation, but apparently is a DbQuery.

Update: I am basing some of my code (the ServiceOp, returning IEnumerable) off of Scott Hanselman's [post here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx):

```
[WebGet]
        public IQueryable<Post> GetPopularPosts()
```

I have setup a basic WCF DataService. As per the [update bug](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/01/21/fix-wcf-data-service-with-entity-framework-code-first-dbcontext-doesn-t-accept-updates.aspx), I defined it as:

```
public class Api : DataService<ObjectContext>
```

rather than as from TestDb. I setup the CreateDataSource() as:

```
protected override ObjectContext CreateDataSource()
{
    var testDb = new TestDb();
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)testDb).ObjectContext;
    objectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    return objectContext;
}
```

In my InitializeService method, I call:

```
config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetStuff", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
```

And my service operation is:

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<Stuff> GetStuff()
{
    var context = new TestDb();
    return context.Stuff;
}
```

The problem is that even though the method completes, and context.Stuff has items in it, the server returns an error:

```
An error occurred while processing this request. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException 
...
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you add the context code here. Is there any relationship between Stuff and other objects in the Context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that a WCF service cannot return interface types! They need to be concrete DataContract-ed types. Especially IQueryable since an IQueryable object is really a "how to call data" instead of actually data.

Try returning a List instead:

```
[WebGet]
public List<Stuff> GetStuff()
{
    var context = new TestDb();
    return context.Stuff.ToList();
}
```

**EDIT**

Apparently you CAN return IEnumerable, but not IQueryable. Which makes sense given my explanation of what IQueryable is.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, that was it. I had based my Service Op off of Scott Hanselman's post (noted above in the update). As a matter of fact, the web is littered with examples returning IQueryable. Ugh...

Comment: Vincent, I want to mark your answer as correct, but I think you need to elaborate on one thing. After doing research on your answer, I found that it might be a bit misleading. You *can* set the return type to an Interface type, but not IQueryable. For instance, IEnumerable is fine. Simply switching out IQueryable for IEnumerable, everything works. You don't need List or the explicit conversion .ToList(). Thanks again for getting me down the right path.